# Python. Draw rectangle in basemap

Tags: python, line, draw, matplotlib-basemap

I need to add several rectangles in my basemap. I nee four rectangles with lat and log ranges as below.

1) llcrnrlon=-10,  urcrnrlon=10, llcrnrlat=35,urcrnrlat=60

2) llcrnrlon=10.5,  urcrnrlon=35, llcrnrlat=35,urcrnrlat=60

3) llcrnrlon=35.5,  urcrnrlon=52, llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlat=55

4) llcrnrlon=-20,  urcrnrlon=35, llcrnrlat=20,urcrnrlat=34.5

My script is below. I found "polygon" packages to add lines but I do not exactly know how to do. Please help me!! Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

```
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

     m=basemaputpart.Basemap(llcrnrlon=-60, llcrnrlat=20, urcrnrlon=60, urcrnrlat=70, resolution='i', projection='cyl', lon_0=0, lat_0=45)

    lon1=np.array([[-180.+j*0.5 for j in range(721)]  for i in range(181)])
    lat1=np.array([[i*0.5 for j in range(721)]  for i in range(181)  ])
    Nx1,Ny1=m(lon1,lat1,inverse=False)

    toplot=data[:,:]
    toplot[data==0]=np.nan
    toplot=np.ma.masked_invalid(toplot)
    plt.pcolor(Nx1,Ny1,np.log(toplot),vmin=0, vmax=5)
    cbar=plt.colorbar()

    m.drawcoastlines(zorder=2)
    m.drawcountries(zorder=2)

    llcrnrlon = -10
    urcrnrlon =  10
    llcrnrlat =  35
    urcrnrlat =  60
    lower_left = (llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat)
    lower_right= (urcrnrlon, llcrnrlat)
    upper_left = (llcrnrlon, urcrnrlat)
    upper_right= (urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat)

    plot_rec(m, lower_left, upper_left, lower_right, upper_right)
```

Then I see "Type Error: 'tuple' object is not callable"

Instead of this part, I added one  you suggested first.

```
    ..
    m.drawcoastlines(zorder=2)
    m.drawcountries(zorder=2)

    def plot_rec(m, lower_left, upper_left, lower_right, upper_right):
        xs = [lower_left[-10], upper_left[-10],
              lower_right[10], upper_right[10]]
        ys = [lower_left[35], upper_left[60],
              lower_right[35], upper_right[60]]
        m.plot(xs,ys,latlon=True)

    plt.show()
```

Then I do not see any box in my plot. I have to put another, not plt.show()??

Also, would you let me know how to put number in the box (e.g., 1 in the upper left conner of the box) ? How to get sum of values in all points of my data and get percentage of (sume of values in the box) over (sum of values in all points of my data)? I ask too much.. Just let me know what you can give me, it would be anyway great!!!

THanks a lot!!

Comment: I've edited my answer to help with the problems you've had implementing my solution. For the other things, you should ask a new question, not append them to this one.

Answer (score 4):

The tricky thing about this is that a 'rectangle' isn't really a 'rectangle' on many, many projection types. So when you say 'rectangle', do you mean an actual rectangle in map-space, or simply a rectangle in pixel-space? The two require very different

But let's assume you want it in map-space. The quickest way is to just use Basemap's [plot](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.plot) method, like so:

```
def plot_rec(bmap, lower_left, upper_left, lower_right, upper_right):
    xs = [lower_left[0], upper_left[0],
          lower_right[0], upper_right[0],
          lower_left[0], lower_right[0],
          upper_left[0], upper_right[0]]
    ys = [lower_left[1], upper_left[1],
          lower_right[1], upper_right[1],
          lower_left[1], lower_right[1],
          upper_left[1], upper_right[1]]
    bmap.plot(xs, ys, latlon = True)
```

where `bmap` is your map, and `lower_left` etc. are lon-lat tuples at those corners.

**Update with use examples:**

You asked for a usage example, so here you go:

```
m=basemaputpart.Basemap(llcrnrlon=-60, llcrnrlat=20, urcrnrlon=60, urcrnrlat=70, resolution='i', projection='cyl', lon_0=0, lat_0=45)

# your other setting up the map code here

# here I draw the first rectangle
llcrnrlon = -10
urcrnrlon =  10
llcrnrlat =  35
urcrnrlat =  60
lower_left = (llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat)
lower_right= (urcrnrlon, llcrnrlat)
upper_left = (llcrnrlon, urcrnrlat)
upper_right= (urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat)

plot_rec(m, lower_left, upper_left, lower_right, upper_right) # This calls the function I defined before

# Rinse and repeat for the other lat/lon combos

plt.show()
```

You can definitely do this more elegantly using list comprehensions to generate the correct corner-point sets, but this should get you started.

**Update 2**

So it appears there is some confusion here. `plot_rec` is a [function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm). It should be placed somewhere not inline with the rest of your script. By itself, it doesn't do anything. It does when you **call** it here:

```
...
upper_left = (llcrnrlon, urcrnrlat)
upper_right= (urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat)
# This next line is where we call the function
plot_rec(m, lower_left, upper_left, lower_right, upper_right)
```

Comment: I do not understand what is lower_left things.. would you give me example using my lat and lon of box??

Comment: and where I have to put this? maybe between "m.drawcountries" and "plt.title"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But, I see TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable. Also, when I tried one you suggested first, I see error (indentation Error: unexpected indent). I might make mistake about space or comma. I am really beginner for python. Please see my update.

Comment: OK, I understand!, but I see an error "IndentationError: expected an indented block" when I type call that function.. It happens from the first line of the calling.

Comment: I can't help you if you paste exactly the code you have. Indentation is important in python, it needs to be exactly correct.

Answer (score 3):

This function bellow should do what you need. *bmap* is your basemap object, and *lonmin,lonmax,latmin,latmax* defines your domain in latitude/longitude terms. You need to call the `plot_rectangle` function after *bmap* has been generated in your code by a call to *Basemap(...).*

```
def plot_rectangle(bmap, lonmin,lonmax,latmin,latmax):
    xs = [lonmin,lonmax,lonmax,lonmin,lonmin]
    ys = [latmin,latmin,latmax,latmax,latmin]
    bmap.plot(xs, ys,latlon = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If, instead, your are looking for rectangles in the map space, whose borders follows paralleles and meridians, the following function works for me. m is the basemap object.

```
 def draw_screen_poly( minlat, maxlat, minlon, maxlon, m):
      lons=np.hstack((np.repeat(minlon,10),\
                      np.linspace(minlon,maxlon, num=10),\
                      np.repeat(maxlon,10),\
                      np.linspace(maxlon,minlon, num=10)))

      lats=np.hstack((np.linspace(minlat,maxlat, num=10),\
                      np.repeat(maxlat,10),\
                      np.linspace(maxlat,minlat, num=10),
                      np.repeat(minlat,10)))

      m.plot(y=lats,x=lons,latlon=True, lw=2, color='navy', alpha=0.8)

      x, y = m(lons, lats)
      xy = zip(x,y)
      poly = Polygon( np.asarray(xy), linewidth=3) 
      ax.add_patch(poly)
```